# Dfs,Bfs, Order issues in Tree traversal

Tags: binary-tree, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

I have a difficulty in understanding the differences between dfs, bfs, and in-order, pre-order and post-order in tree traversal (binary tree).

My understanding that 
dfs is neither pre-order, in-order or post-order
Bfs is also neither pre-order, in-order or post-order
But I see pre-order, in-order or post-order versions in dfs in wikipedia, anybody knows why?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: You can view the wikipedia article **specifically about DFS** to understand the relation as my another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243105/breadth-first-search-traversal-vs-pre-order-traversal-vs-depth-first-search-trav#comment137378609_55243795) says. For BFS, you can view this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243795/21294350).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depended on what order you visit the nodes in your recursive function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search.28DFS.29

If you visit the left child tree, then current node, then right child tree, the iterator will come put in order because the first node to be read will be the far right leaf, then it's parent, then it's parent's right leaf, etc.

Other arrangements of these operations will result in other orderings.