# Breadth First Search Traversal VS Pre-order Traversal VS Depth First Search Traversal

Tags: binary-tree, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal, preorder

For a binary tree, is *Breadth First Search traversal* (BFS) the same as *Pre-order traversal*? I am a little bit confused by these two different types of traversals.

Additionally, how does *Pre-order traversal* compare to *Depth First Search traversal* (DFS)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, **pre-order traversal is actually a form of Depth-First-Search (DFS) traversal**. There are three different forms of DFS, namely:

1. Pre-Order
2. In-Order
3. Post-Order

To prove that Breadth-First-Search (BFS) traversal isn't the same as pre-order traversal *I will show a counter example* below:

To be clear a **binary tree isn't the same as a binary search tree**, namely a binary tree can be defined as:

**Binary Tree** - A tree whose elements have at most 2 children is called a binary tree. Note there is no mentioning of the ordering of the children.

Ok now to the counter-example, take the following simple binary tree:

[image: counter example binary tree]

For a pre-order traversal the nodes are visited in the following order:
**Pre-Order:** [1,2,4,3]

now for Breadth-First-Search traversal the nodes are visited in the following order:

**BFS:** [1,2,3,4]

**Note: pre-order traversal is different from the BFS traversal.**

For more information on the different tree traversals check out this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: Great answer. In addition, something that may help to visualize the difference is that a pre-order search is typically implemented using a Stack data structure, whilst BFS typically uses a Queue. This is because BFS prioritizes a nodes neighbors, whilst preorder DFS prioritizes a nodes children.

Comment: @ifiore Thank you, yes you're correct :) DFS uses a stack and BFS uses a queue for their underlying implementations.

Comment: 1. More specifically, "pre-order" is the [visiting order by DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings) where "This is a compact and natural way of describing the progress of the search" is shown in the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Example). 2. BFS uses [level-order search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search) because searching level by level (i.e. depth by depth).

Answer (score 8):

DFS types are pre-order , in-order and post-order;

DFS is like - first go for my descendants (grand-grand-..child) then I will see my siblings descendants.
BFS is like - first go for my siblings then their child then their child and so on.

pre-order DFS technique is generally used in graph traversal .

in-order traversal only in binary tree.(tree is special kind of graph)

BFS is a level order traversal in the case of tree.

[image: traversing in a binary tree]

These four are different techniques of traversal and results are also
different.
Sometimes their result might be same so don't get confused, check for different tree and you will find out difference.

Comment: I think In the above answer the Postorder Traversal is incorrect, the correct Postorder Traversal would be : 4,5,2,6,7,3,1

Comment: Yes you are right, I will correct it, actually if you traverse like
Right child then left child then print
It will show
7635421